# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity on Lg series

Tags: android, onactivityresult

When, I take photo I recieve error below. Note that app works perfectly on HTC rhyme and galaxy tab 7.7. How It can be fixed?

```
    08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend/ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.AddFillActivityApp}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=12, result=-1, data=null} to activity {ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend/ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.AddFillActivityApp}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2608)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2636)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2103)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3576)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:138)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4905)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=12, result=-1, data=null} to activity {ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend/ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.AddFillActivityApp}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3205)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    ... 13 more
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1094)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:354)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:313)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:49)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.AddFillActivityApp.getRealPathFromURI(AddFillActivityApp.java:844)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.AddFillActivityApp.onActivityResult(AddFillActivityApp.java:704)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5492)
08-06 13:18:29.084: E/AndroidRuntime(27803):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3201)
```

forResult call

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,
                                        "zdanie " + c.getTime());
                                mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver()
                                        .insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                                values);
                                Intent intentPicture = new Intent(
                                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                intentPicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                        mCapturedImageURI);
                                startActivityForResult(intentPicture, 12);
```

onResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 12 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // photo1 = getRealPathFromURI(mCapturedImageURI);
            saveFile(
                    decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                            getRealPathFromURI(mCapturedImageURI), 800, 800), 1);
            pho1.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                    getRealPathFromURI(mCapturedImageURI), 80, 60));
            miss1 = 1;

        } 
}
```

getRealPath

```
   public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        if (contentUri==null){
            Log.e("RealPath", "URI: null");
        }else Log.e("RealPath", "URI: "+contentUri.toString());
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext(),
                    contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("RealPath", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

StackTrace from realpath catch block

```
   08-06 15:33:23.520: W/System.err(22083): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 15:33:23.536: W/System.err(22083):    at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1097)
08-06 15:33:23.544: W/System.err(22083):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:357)
08-06 15:33:23.544: W/System.err(22083):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:316)
08-06 15:33:23.544: W/System.err(22083):    at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:49)
08-06 15:33:23.544: W/System.err(22083):    at ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.AddFillActivityApp.getRealPathFromURI(AddFillActivityApp.java:842)
08-06 15:33:23.544: W/System.err(22083):    at ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.AddFillActivityApp.onActivityResult(AddFillActivityApp.java:733)
08-06 15:33:23.544: W/System.err(22083):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5436)
08-06 15:33:23.544: W/System.err(22083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3188)
08-06 15:33:23.544: W/System.err(22083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2592)
08-06 15:33:23.544: W/System.err(22083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
08-06 15:33:23.544: W/System.err(22083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
08-06 15:33:23.544: W/System.err(22083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3563)
08-06 15:33:23.544: W/System.err(22083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-06 15:33:23.544: W/System.err(22083):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
08-06 15:33:23.544: W/System.err(22083):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 15:33:23.552: W/System.err(22083):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 15:33:23.552: W/System.err(22083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849)
08-06 15:33:23.552: W/System.err(22083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 15:33:23.552: W/System.err(22083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-06 15:33:23.552: W/System.err(22083):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
08-06 15:33:23.559: W/System.err(22083):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
08-06 15:33:23.559: W/System.err(22083):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT** I made test on 5 more phones and evrything works fine. Only LG phone cause problem.
**EDIT:** I tried to use cursor loader instead of managed queries. Same problemms

Comment: Can you post the code for `getRealPathFromURI()` method?

Comment: gonna gamble an say `mCapturedImageURI` is null

Comment: I poasted realpath:), assume it is null, why it is null only on one of 3 of my devices?)

Comment: little hint: in the catch()-block of getRealPathFromURI(), log the exception to find the reason what is causing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are wondering why it works without any problems on some devices, and some devices not:

as you probably see - the camera app is not the same app. in fact, each camera app is entirely different,  even the ones coming with your stock.

what's to this and your problem? -  no one prevents applications that reacts to `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`  ignoring completely the  `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` intent extra.

your code assume that the application been selected by the user (or the default camera app installed) will store for sure the captured image in the path specified.   unfortionatly, I know from experience that it not always true.

sad but true.  you can't count on `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` if you think your users would use such camera apps, or specific devices like the LG series default camera app.

in this case, maybe you could get the image by the approach suggested by @Arun C Thomas,but as I sad - getData() not necessarily brings you anything also, if the camera app did not stored the data itself in the result.

that's why you must varify null, or doing some "try/catch" to prevent your app from crashing on this cases...

Answer (score 0):

mostly the Cursor returned is `null` so it is crashing when you are trying to get the `column_index`.

```
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
```